# Closest Linestring to given points using POSTGIS

Tags: sql, geolocation, geospatial, postgis, openstreetmap

I am trying to find for each given Point with Lat and Lon coordinates its closest LineString. Each LineString represents a way imported into Postgis from OSM data using osm2pgsql.

The ways table stores 612482 entries and has a custom geom column created by a custom lua import script.

```
tables.ways = osm2pgsql.define_way_table('ways', {
    { column = 'tags', type = 'jsonb' },
    { column = 'geom', type = 'linestring', not_null = true },
})

function osm2pgsql.process_way(object)

    if clean_tags(object.tags) then
        return
    end

    tables.ways:insert({
        tags = object.tags,
        geom = object:as_linestring()
    })

end
```

The ways table has a spatial index created with:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ways_geom ON ways USING GIST (geom);
```

The sql query running is as follows:

```
SELECT
    points.point_geom AS input_point,
    closest_way.*,
    ST_Distance(ST_Transform(closest_way.geom, 4326), points.point_geom) * 111195 AS distance
FROM
    (
        VALUES
            (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.411147474894877, 52.52171818609274), 4326)),
            (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.411147474894877, 52.52171818609274), 4326)),
            (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.411147474894877, 52.52171818609274), 4326)),
            (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.411147474894877, 52.52171818609274), 4326)),
            (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.411147474894877, 52.52171818609274), 4326)),
            (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.386413537668519, 52.47060159563416), 4326))
    ) AS points (point_geom)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        ways.*
    FROM
        ways
    ORDER BY
        ST_Transform(ways.geom, 4326) <-> points.point_geom
    LIMIT 1
) AS closest_way;
```

Explain yields the following

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Nested Loop  (cost=16140799.73..96845098.61 rows=6 width=486)"
"  ->  Values Scan on ""*VALUES*""  (cost=0.00..0.08 rows=6 width=32)"
"  ->  Limit  (cost=16140799.73..16140799.73 rows=1 width=454)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=16140799.73..16142330.94 rows=612482 width=454)"
"              Sort Key: ((st_transform(ways.geom, 4326) <-> ""*VALUES*"".column1))"
"              ->  Seq Scan on ways  (cost=0.00..16137737.32 rows=612482 width=454)"
```

The query resolves in 5s which in my mind is quite slow for only 6 input points.
Is there anything I can do to speed it up because I need to look up multiple thousand of points and a query with 1k points doesn't even resolve in 10 minutes.
Thanks in advance